# Origen de expresiones como "cada dos por tres"

Tags: modismos, significado, historia

Iba a preguntar por el origen de la expresión "cada dos por tres", pero al ir a buscarla en el diccionario me he encontrado con la siguiente [variedad de expresiones](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EA0Jc84):

> **a cada dos por tres**
>   1. loc. adv. cada dos por tres.
>
> **a dos por tres**
>   1. loc. adv. coloq. Pronta y claramente.
>
> **cada dos por tres**
>   1. loc. adv. Con frecuencia.
>
> **en un dos por tres**
>   1. loc. adv. coloq. En un momento, rápidamente.

Por un lado hay un par de expresiones que usan el "dos por tres" para indicar algo hecho rápidamente, y otras dos que implican algo hecho con frecuencia. Imagino que estas expresiones tendrán un origen común, así que pregunto: ¿de dónde provienen estas expresiones?

> Yo no escribo con plumaje,
>   sino con pluma, pues ya
>   tanto bien barbado da
>   en escribir al revés.
>   Óyeme tú dos por tres
>   lo que digo de pe a pa.
>
> Francisco de Quevedo y Villegas, "Poesías", 1597-1645 (España).

Comment: Yo tenía la hipótesis de que podía estar relacionado con la música. Algo así como que los compases de 2x3 o 2x4 fuesen los más rápidos y de ahí la expresión. El problema para empezar es que no hay compás de 2/3. Básicamente el numerador indica los tiempos que caben en el compás y el denominador el tipo de figura. Yo tengo escasa formación musical, pero después de investigar un poco no he podido encontrar nada que sustentase mi hipótesis.

Comment: @Diego yo también lo pensé, pero en música los compases tienen siempre un denominador que es potencia de 2, dado que indica el tipo de nota base y las notas son todas siempre la mitad de la nota precedente. Así, 1 sería la redonda, 2 la blanca (mitad de la redonda), 4 la negra (mitad de la blanca), 8 la corchea (mitad de la negra) y así sucesivamente. Luego no existe el compás de 2 por 3.

Comment: Lo aprendí mientras investigaba. Dije, lo mismo "2 por 3" es una corrupción de "dos por cuatro" o similar, peor luego me di cuenta de que lo estaba forzando demasiado.

Comment: Agrego un ejemplo en el sentido en el que se entiende (por _muy frecuentemente_) que está  [en la hermosa letra][1] de una [canción infantil de María Elena Walsh][2] (en el minuto 1:34 de la "Canción de tomar el té") 

> (...) / Los pobres coladores / 
tienen mucha sed / 
porque el agua se les escapa / 
***cada dos por tres.*** 


  [1]: https://www.cmtv.com.ar/discos_letras/letra.php?bnid=1992&banda=Maria_Elena_Walsh&DS_DS=7504&tmid=94337&tema=CANCI%D3N_DE_TOMAR_EL_T%C9
  [2]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J9-zuXuGeME

Answer (score 5):

No conocía la expresión "cada dos por tres", pero sí uso "en un dos por tres".

Yo imagino que se refiere a que la operación `2 x 3 = 6` es muy fácil de recordar, no tiene ninguna dificultad y se responde así de rápido. Por lo tanto, puede usarse en expresiones que dan a entender que algo es "fácil", "claro" o "rápido" y, por extensión, algo "frecuente".

Me parece que esto es lo más simple de entender, y por ahora no creo que haya alguna explicación histórica más complicada.

Answer (score 5):

[*Obras de Don Francisco de Quevedo Villegas coleccion completa ..., Volume 2*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Nc5eXxgkcccC&pg=PA401&dq="dos+por+tres") (1859) dice esto en la nota a pie de página sobre el uso de la frase *dos por tres* en [*Cuento de cuentos*](http://www.cervantesvirtual.com/obra/cuento-de-cuentos--0/) (1580-1645):

> *Le dije dos por tres.* - *A dos por tres* se usa hoy para expresar que alguno dice ó hace alguna cosa con prontitud ó sin miedo ni reparo; **tan pronto como se multiplica dos por tres.**

Answer (score 0):

No estoy muy convencido, pero, según Andrés Ospina, en su Refranario bogotano, la frase proviene del comerciante libanés que popularizó la consigna ‘pague dos, lleve tres’ en los años 40 del pasado siglo. Al parecer, según Ospino, "Debido al flujo y a la forma con la que la mercancía se evaporaba de los anaqueles, se afincó la creencia popular de que un ‘dos por tres’ era sinónimo de velocidad...  *Se non é vero é ben trovato*

Answer (score 0):

Pienso que la locución "**cada 2 por 3**", podría proceder de  una deformación de la frase "2 de cada 3", la cual tiene connotación de frecuencia, rapidez y hasta de intensidad que se encuentra simbolizada en una relación matemática simple que supera siempre la media (2 es el 66,6...% de 3).

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. Entra en contradicción con las otras respuestas, ¿podrías aportar referencias que sustenten tu hipótesis? Dale a [edit] para añadirlas, ¡gracias!

Comment: Lo siento, no tengo referencias; se trata solo de una hipótesis personal.