# Origin and documentation of meaning: "dos tres" as *so-so*

Tags: definiciones, diferencias-regionales, historia, modismos

Inspired by [Origen de expresiones como "cada dos por tres"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23210/9385).

I'm familiar with an expression used in, at least, Mexico: **dos tres**.  It is a way of giving a lukewarm reaction to a question.  For example:

> A: ¿Cómo te va, compañera?
>
> B: Dos tres.  Casi no he dormido, al nene le está saliendo un nuevo diente y está súper inquieto ahorita.

Here's what I'm wondering:

- Where did this expression come from?
- Does it show up anywhere else besides Mexico?
- Is the meaning documented in any dictionary?  So far the only place I found it was in the spanishdict.com entry for *Responses to "¿Cómo Estás?"*.  I also tried I tried *Así Hablamos* and DLE.

Answer (score 2):

[*Diccionario del español de México. Volumen 1*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=GqDQCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT717&lpg=PT717&dq="c%C3%B3mo+est%C3%A1s"+"dos+tres") claims that "dos tres" is a variant of "dos [que] tres":

[image]

[*Guatemalan Spanish: Speak like a Native!*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=qo8nAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA26&lpg=PA26&dq="dos+que+tres") makes the (unsubstantiated) claim that this phrase comes from an American language:

> #### *dos que tres*
>
> This construction also came from Mayan languages such as Cachiquel, Kekchi, and Quiche. In these languages **dos que tres** means *some*.

Answer (score 1):

As a Mexican I really don't know the answer. In Mexico we play a lot with the language and create new phrases every now and then, and sometimes we adopt them for a while, later we stop using them.

My understanding is that we are actually trying to say 2/3 or two thirds, not half bad, but not totally good, and I actually have used "dos tercios" that simplified ends up being "dos tres".

The original or most used term for this is "mas o menos" meaning more or less (good/bad).